# Set public field of unmanaged C dll from C#

Tags: c#, dll, delegates, interop, dllimport

I am writing a C# binding for an unmanaged C dll.

The dll provides 5 hooks to return several data:

```
typedef void (*t_libpd_printhook)(const char *recv);
```

and exports a field like:

```
 EXTERN t_libpd_printhook libpd_printhook;
```

now i was using [Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) to generate the binding code, which gave me just a delegate definition:

```
public delegate void t_libpd_printhook([In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string recv);
```

So is there some magic Interop function call i can use, to set the t_libpd_printhook field in the DLL?

Comment: ah, didn't know of that one, but how would i assign a delegate to it then?

Comment: yep, i accepted your answer now, as its the correct answer to my question. but as the dll i use is open source, i will probably add the setter methods as usr suggested. i found this to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167895/howto-implement-callback-interface-from-unmanaged-dll-to-net-app

Comment: Interesting question and I do agree that a setter is the right solution if you are compiling the native code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to obtain a pointer to the exported `libpd_printhook` variable. You can then use `Marshal.WriteIntPtr` and `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` to assign to the delegate.

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, 
    SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

.....

IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary(@"mydll.dll");
IntPtr plibpd_printhook = GetProcAddress(lib, "libpd_printhook");
Marshal.WriteIntPtr(plibpd_printhook, 
    Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(mydelegate));
FreeLibrary(lib);
```

You will want to add the error checking that I excised in the interests of a concise example.

Now, if you are in control of the unmanaged library I would still recommend adding a function to encapsulate writing to this function pointer. That feels like a better interface to me.

Comment: thank you, very good example! i will evaluate both ways. as i have the sources of the dll i can write the setter methods, which is less work and the cleaner interface as you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

PInvoke does not support exported variable. You need to create an unmanaged function which takes your delegate and copies it into the field.

Comment: allright, so i have to add the set methods in C... thank you!