# Interop causes Unity to crash

Tags: c#, c, callback, interop, unity-game-engine

**is it possible at all to make C/C++ function callback into Unity scripts, provided that you can create a new thread from the scripts?** I tried but Unity crashes as soon as the scripts get executed.

I googled about it and found [this thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/201598/interop-wrapper-causes-unity-crash.html) which says

> Unity is not callback nor threadsafe, any access to classes that
>   extend UnityEngine.Object is only allowed from within the same thread
>   as unity scripts are running in, not asyncronous from other threads
>   nor from asyncrnous callbacks from COM / OS async operations
>
> If thats the case for you there are two possible ways:
>
> (1) Write a wrapper that gets these callbacks and queues the stuff and
>   then expose a function that allows unity to request the next event /
>   dataobject or whatever in a blocking, unthreaded form (2) Make the
>   callbacks call into a static function on something extending from
>   System.Object and write the same kind of logic as above to request the
>   information on classes extending UnityEngine.Object

**But I think if I create a thread and callback into that thread, it will be okay right?** I am thinking like this because I've read threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167895/howto-implement-callback-interface-from-unmanaged-dll-to-net-app) that introduces how to make C functions calling back C# functions. So I reasoned that if I create a new thread, it's no longer Unity, it will just be mono and C#.

Here is my code that crashes Unity:

The C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
// #include "stdafx.h"

typedef int (__stdcall * Callback)(const char* text);

Callback Handler = 0;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void __stdcall SetCallback(Callback handler) {
    Handler = handler;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void __stdcall TestCallback() {
    int retval = Handler("hello world");
}
```

The C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;


class UnManagedInterop : MonoBehaviour {
  private delegate int Callback(string text);
  private Callback mInstance;   // Ensure it doesn't get garbage collected


  public void Test() {
        mInstance = new Callback(Handler);
        SetCallback(mInstance);
        TestCallback();
  }

  private int Handler(string text) {
    // Do something...
    print(text);
    return 42;
  }

  [DllImport("test0")]
  private static extern void SetCallback(Callback fn);
  [DllImport("test0")]
  private static extern void TestCallback();

    void Start()
    {
        Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test));

        // Start the thread
        oThread.Start();


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered whether or not the crash you are experiencing is due to not marshaling the string in C++ before passing it back up to C# (Unity) (i.e. using 'mono_string_new()' -- see http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono#Creating_objects)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**!

I tested again on August 8, 2012, with Unity 3.5.2f2, Pro license. Thanks for @hatboyzero's comment I found [this example](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono#C.23_to_C_delegate_registration).

Although the code in my question doesn't work, the following code works:

```
// C#
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Demo {
    delegate int MyCallback1 (int a, int b);

    [DllImport ("MyRuntime")]
    extern static void RegisterCallback (MyCallback1 callback1);

    static int Add (int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    static int Sub (int a, int b) { return a - b; }

    void Init ()
    {
        // This one registers the method "Add" to be invoked back by C code
        RegisterCallback (Add);
    }
}


// C
typedef int (*callback_t) (int a, int b);
static callback_t my_callback;

void RegisterCallback (callback_t cb)
{
    my_callback = cb;
}

int InvokeManagedCode (int a, int b)
{
    if (my_callback == NULL){
         printf ("Managed code has not initialized this library yet");
         abort ();
    }
    return (*my_callback) (a, b);
}
```

I didn't have to embed MonoRuntime as the tutorial suggests. Just the above two pieces of code solved my problem.

Comment: I've almost done the same thing but I still see a crash. Instead of adding two variables, I'm trying to create a new texture but I think creating a texture requires to be run in render thread. How can I do this?