# How to talk to UI from native c++ in WP8?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8

I am new to WP8/c#, overloaded with new information and definetly missing something.

I have wp8 application that uses native code library. How can i notify UI about changes from native code? 
I understood that i cannot pass callbacks from c# function to to native c++ on wp8.
Simple code below illustrates what i want:

### MainPage cs

```
namespace phoneapp
{
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    testRT _testrt;
    public MainPage()
    {
      _testrt= new testRT();
    }
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      _testrt->foo();
    }
  }
}
```

### runtime component cpp

```
namespace rtc
{
  public ref class testRT sealed
  {
    public:
      testRT();
      void foo();
    private:
      test* _test;
  };
}
testRT::testRT()
{
  _test= new test();
}
testRT::foo()
{
  _test->foothread();
}
```

### native class cpp

```
test::test()
{
}
test::~test()
{
}
void test::foothread()
{
  signal_UI_status("started");
  while (notfinished)
  {
    //do something
    ...
    signal_UI_results("found %i results", res);
  }
  signal_UI_status("finished");
}
```

What is the best way to implement such "signal" functionality on windows phone? callback? namedpipe? socket?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto implement callback interface from unmanaged DLL to .net app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167895/howto-implement-callback-interface-from-unmanaged-dll-to-net-app) - there's probably a better match, but this has been asked so many times, searching on c++/c#/callback turns up a lot of noise

Comment: well, not exactly - it's not .net app: windows phone 8 uses native library through windows phone runtime component in c++/cx

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a callback delegate in Windows Runtime and pass a C# function back to it.

```
public delegate void WinRtCallback(Platform::String^ resultString);

public ref class testRT sealed
{
public:
  testRT();
  void foo(WinRtCallback^ callback);
private:
  test* _test;
};
```

Or even better you could get your C++ to return an asynchronous operation (via `IAsyncAction` and other async interfaces), but that's much more advanced.

More information about that is on MSDN as ["Creating Asynchronous Operations in C++ for Windows Store Apps"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750082.aspx), which applies to Windows Phone apps as well.